# Integral of the complex function $\frac1{\cos z}$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

I need to solve this integral **without** residue theorem, Could you help me?

$$\int_\limits C\frac{1}{\cos{z}}\mathrm dz$$

Where $C$ is the circumference of radius $1$ centered at $\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $z\in \mathbb{C}$.

Thank you!

Comment: That only leaves Cauchy integral formula, have you tried finding the Laurent expansion for this centered at the center of the circle?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using  the fact that $\cos (\pi /2+z)=-\sin z$ we can write this as $-i\int_{\gamma} \frac  1 {\sin z} dz$ where $\gamma$ is the circle of radius $1$ centered at $0$. To evaluate this let $f(z)=\frac z {\sin z }$ for $z \neq 0$, $f(0)=1$. and apply CIF: $\int_{\gamma} \frac {f(z)} z dz=2\pi i f(0)=2\pi i$.